# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when running gradle sonarRunner

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube

I run into an issue when running the sonarRunner task on a sample Android application called "Sample Project" with Gradle.

I have the following configuration in mt build.gradle script:

```
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000/"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "org.h2.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "sonar"
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.test", "src/test/java"
        property "sonar.binaries", "build"
    }
}
```

So when I run:

```
gradle sonarRunner
```

I get:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Sample Project:sonarRunner'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Using the command:

```
gradle sonarRunner --stacktrace
```

I got:

```
.
.
.
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 89: http://localhost:9000/batch_bootstrap/properties?project=com.company.demo.gradle:Sample Project&amp;dryRun=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace I noticed that the issue is because of the wide space int the URL used by the plugin:

```
http://localhost:9000/batch_bootstrap/properties?project=com.company.demo.gradle:Sample Project&amp;dryRun=false
```

To fix this issue I added another property in my build.gradle script:

```
property "sonar.projectKey", "standard-project-layout:sample-project"
```

This fixed the problem for me, so now my the configuration for my build.gradle script looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000/"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "org.h2.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "sonar"
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.test", "src/test/java"
        property "sonar.binaries", "build"

        // There is a problem when using "standard-project-layout:Sample Project" (by default)
        // because of the wide space
         property "sonar.projectKey", "standard-project-layout:sample-project"
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. It's a known limitation of the underlying sonar-runner library used by Gradle, and should be fixed there (e.g. by printing an appropriate error message).